# String to TextBox plus new line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
string test ="0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 01234567890";
TextBox.Text = test;
```

The problem is string not jumping in a new line,

```
|------------------------------|
|                              |
|                              |
|0123456789 0123456789 01234567|89 0123456789 01234567890
|                              |
|                              |
|<----------<------>---------->|
```

How to fix it ?

1) String start from left up corner.

2) String CAN'T go over the box

Comment: is the string single line or multiline?

Comment: asp-classic has text boxes? Isn't asp-classic vbscript embedded with html? Am I missing something or did you mean asp.net webforms?

Answer (score 5):

You need to Enable Multi-Line Option from the Properties of the Text Box.

Answer (score 3):

There is multiline property on textbox. By default it renders as INPUT which is single line, with multiline it will render as TEXTAREA.

Note that you need both `TextMode = TextBox.MultiLine` and `Wrap=true;` on that element as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.wrap).

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="Comment"
       TextMode="MultiLine"
       Columns="50"
       Rows="5"
       runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply ,you can do like this:

```
 TextBox.Multiline = true;
```

If you want to add vertical scrollbar in multiline textbox, you can do;

```
TextBox.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
```